# hierarchical-checkboxes: not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the below link to create a hierarchical treeview.

https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/tree/hierarchical-checkboxes/

It should be displayed like the below:
[image]

However, when I am using it, it displays like this (checkmarks, arrow etc missing):

[image]

My code is below(ui.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/smart.default.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/smart.tree.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="viewport">

    <smart-tree id="tree"  has-three-states selection-mode="checkBox">
        <smart-tree-item>IPV4</smart-tree-item>
        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_TNAT
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_SNAT_ZBFW
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>


        <smart-tree-item>MCAST</smart-tree-item>
        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_MCAST
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_MCAST
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-item>IPV6</smart-tree-item>
        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSECV6
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSECV6_QOSV6_DPI_FNF
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>
    </smart-tree>

</body>
</html>
```

My code structure is:

[image]

I have copied the 2 files under static:

1. smart.default.css
2. smart.tree.js

I am new to this and any help to get the same UI would be encouraging.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the file paths. Try using absolute path for the .css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have missed adding the required styles.

```html
<link href="https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/styles/demos.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/styles/codepen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/source/styles/smart.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/source/smart.elements.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/scripts/data.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/smart.default.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/smart.tree.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="viewport">

    <smart-tree id="tree"  has-three-states selection-mode="checkBox">
        <smart-tree-item>IPV4</smart-tree-item>
        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_TNAT
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_SNAT_ZBFW
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>


        <smart-tree-item>MCAST</smart-tree-item>
        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_MCAST
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSEC_QOS_DPI_FNF_MCAST
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-item>IPV6</smart-tree-item>
        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSECV6
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>

        <smart-tree-items-group>
            IPSECV6_QOSV6_DPI_FNF
            <smart-tree-item>IMIX</smart-tree-item>
            <smart-tree-item>1400</smart-tree-item>
        </smart-tree-items-group>
    </smart-tree>

</body>
</html>
```